# sails js Model keeps an array of ObjectId

Tags: sails.js

I have a User collection and a Partner collection.

I would like to make a field "like" in User that keeps tract of a list of Partner that the user has liked.

How do I write the model here?

```
User Collection:

{
    name: "string",
    password: "string",
    likes: {
        collection: "partner",
        via: "user"
    }
}
```

But when I load this code. The server simply won't start, and it throws me an error.

```
Error occurred lifting Sails app:  [Error: on mapping custom foreign keys: user->partner. Attribute: `user` does not exist on: collection: `partner`]
```

Comment: I suppose what you are looking for is to create a `many-to-many` relationship between user and partner.
Check out more here: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming because you may want a model to have multiple many-to-many associations on another model, a `via` key is needed on the collection attribute. This states which model attribute on the one side of the association is used to populate the records.

In your Partner models attribute list, add an attribute user, like this

`user: {
   model: 'user'
 }`

Have a look on [this link](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/many-to-many)

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside attributes array of your `User` model.

```
likes: {
    collection: 'partner',
    via: 'user',
    dominant: true
}
```